# pandas dataframe to json by

Tags: python, json, dataframe, format

I have this data table in excel:
[data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMudw.png)

I want to convert it into below format in json:

```
[
    {
        "name": "A",
        "time": 1000,
        "value": 3
    },
    {
        "name": "B",
        "time": 1000,
        "value": 7
    },
    {
        "name": "C",
        "time": 1000,
        "value": 3
    },
    {
        "name": "A",
        "time": 2000,
        "value": 7
    },
    {
        "name": "B",
        "time": 2000,
        "value": 3
    },
    {
        "name": "C",
        "time": 2000,
        "value": 9
    }
]
```

I tried multiple formats but none of them works. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most compute efficient but this will do the job. First of all read in your excel file to a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_excel("<name>.xlsx")
```

Then use dictionary comprehension and zip:

```
json_list = [{"time":time, "a":a, "b":b, "c":c} for time, a, b, c in zip(df["Time"], df["A"], df["B"], df["C"])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did it with `melt`

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'time': [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000],
    'A': [3, 7, 6, 1, 7],
    'B': [7, 3, 6, 6, 5],
    'C': [9, 9, 5, 3, 5]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

long_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['time'], var_name='name')
json = long_df.to_json(orient='records')
print(json)
```